# Dotnet set up in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I have just upgraded to dotnet 5 from 3.1 on my Linux machine and when I try to create a new console or any project I get the following error

> dotnet new console

```
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3, String path4)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.EngineEnvironmentSettings.DefaultPathInfo.get_BaseDir()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Paths.UserPaths.get_AliasesFile()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.AliasRegistry.EnsureLoaded()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.AliasRegistry.TryExpandCommandAliases(IReadOnlyList`1 inputTokens, IReadOnlyList`1& expandedInputTokens)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.AliasSupport.TryExpandAliases(INewCommandInput commandInput, AliasRegistry aliasRegistry)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.AliasSupport.CoordinateAliasExpansion(INewCommandInput commandInput, AliasRegistry aliasRegistry, ITelemetryLogger telemetryLogger)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.CommandParsing.NewCommandInputCli.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<OnExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

This error appears almost at any command I try to run.

Extract from dotnet --info:

```
    .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: have you tried specifying a path for the output with `-o "yourpath"`...it shouldn't be required but maybe it helps

Comment: dotnet new console -o "/path" is giving me the same error